@RefreshScope behaviour with Spring Boot Native Image
As I understand it currently, the reason why @RefreshScope is not supported within native-images is that dynamically changing the environment's config might cause the service to break.
I'm currently using Consul K/V to store translation pack and business/error copytext configs (not related to the service's environment config). I have tested a native image compiled service with @RefreshScope, and it works just as the non-native build does (the service reinitialize the bean with latest consul k\v values).
For my use case, is it safe to use @RefreshScope? I couldn't find any references aside from the documentation, which mentions it is not supported.
